# Conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime. Out-of-range error

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a strange error with my SQL Query.

This works:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_SomeTable(Send_Type,Remote_Eml,Cover_Subj,Cover_Note,AtnId,StandortEinsatzValue,Standort,KundenNr,AtnTel,Name,Strasse,AtnName,AreaManagerContact,Datum,PLZOrt)
VALUES ('2', '', '', '','02832','1','Replaced','2001158207','Replaced','Real','Replaced','Replaced','Replaced','10.12.2016','15745 Replaced')
```

This gives me an error:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_SomeTable(Send_Type,Remote_Eml,Cover_Subj,Cover_Note,AtnId,StandortEinsatzValue,Standort,KundenNr,AtnTel,Name,Strasse,AtnName,AreaManagerContact,Datum,PLZOrt)
VALUES ('2', '', '', '','02832','1','Replaced','2001158207','Replaced','Real','Replaced','Replaced','Replaced','17.12.2016','15745 Replaced')
```

> The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted
>   in an out-of-range value.

Only difference is the date. "10.12.2016" vs "17.12.2016".
Column "Datum" is of type "datetime".

We use a SQL Server 2016.

Can you help me?

Comment: `17` is out of range for a month value, and your engine is likely parsing dates as en-US. Do not use culture-dependent strings like `10.12.2016` to insert data. The only recognized independent string format is `20161210` (ISO with no separators). Better yet, use an actual typed `DATETIME` parameter.

Comment: SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, Datum, 101) FROM table

Comment: Either of these comments should work.  Use the literal `'20161212'`, or use `CONVERT` with the appropriate format mask number.

Comment: Sounds logical. Thank you very much

Comment: The SQL Server takes Dates in the format of MM-DD-YYYY or YYYY-MM-DD. Also, While Storing it to the Table you can use CAST('12-17-2016' AS DATE)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use CONVERT for this. Replace your queries as below.

Also maintain a standardised date formats in the DB.

```
INSERT INTO tbl_SomeTable(Send_Type,Remote_Eml,Cover_Subj,Cover_Note,AtnId,StandortEinsatzValue,Standort,KundenNr,AtnTel,Name,Strasse,AtnName,AreaManagerContact,Datum,PLZOrt)
VALUES ('2', '', '', '','02832','1','Replaced','2001158207','Replaced','Real','Replaced','Replaced','Replaced',CONVERT(DATETIME,'10.12.2016',103),'15745 Replaced')

INSERT INTO tbl_SomeTable(Send_Type,Remote_Eml,Cover_Subj,Cover_Note,AtnId,StandortEinsatzValue,Standort,KundenNr,AtnTel,Name,Strasse,AtnName,AreaManagerContact,Datum,PLZOrt)
VALUES ('2', '', '', '','02832','1','Replaced','2001158207','Replaced','Real','Replaced','Replaced','Replaced',CONVERT(DATETIME,'17.12.2016',103),'15745 Replaced')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME,'17.12.2016',103)
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME,'10.12.2016',103)
```